# How to get the binary path from a chocolatey shim?

Tags: .net, chocolatey, shim

I need to extract the [product version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.productversion?view=netcore-3.1) from a binary in .NET. This works with the actual binary. However, when a chocolatey shim is referenced, then I only get the product version of the shim. Is there a way to programmatically read the path to the binary from the shim?

Answer (score 0):

I found it myself - calling the shim with the parameter `--shimgen-help` will also ouptut the target path.